# Creating a sockaddr without casting

Tags: c, sockets, vxworks

I would like to create a `sockaddr` struct without the funny casting because I have a function that will return `sockaddr` structs. But I cannot really figure out how to re-pack the data from a `sockaddr_in` to a `sockaddr`. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/%7Epxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html) that shows this done like this

```
struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
myaddr.sin_port = htons(0);
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr);
```

I have a function to return regular `sockaddr`

```
sockaddr CreateAddress(std::string ip, uint16_t port){
    sockaddr_in address = {0};
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    // return as sockaddr instead..
    sockaddr addr = {0};
    addr.sa_len = sizeof(sockaddr);
    addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    // how to fill in sockaddr.sa_data?
    // maybe like this?
    addr.sa_data[0] = (address.sin_port >> 8) & 0xFF;
    addr.sa_data[1] = (address.sin_port) & 0xFF;
    addr.sa_data[2] = (address.sin_addr.s_addr >> 24) & 0xFF;
    addr.sa_data[3] = (address.sin_addr.s_addr >> 16) & 0xFF;
    addr.sa_data[4] = (address.sin_addr.s_addr >> 8) & 0xFF;
    addr.sa_data[5] = (address.sin_addr.s_addr) & 0xFF;
    return addr;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C code. Are your sure your C tag is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket API functions are built to take a `struct sockaddr *` as a parameter because there are multiple socket address types that it could accept, i.e. `struct sockaddr_un` for UNIX domain sockets, `struct sockaddr_in` for IPv4, `struct sockaddr_in6` for IPv6, etc.  The `struct sockaddr` type is how the socket API (written in C) implements inheritance.

As such, these functions don't actually expect that a `struct sockaddr *` parameter actually points to a struct of that type.  Based on the socket type, it will internally cast it to the proper type.

This means that you should work with `struct sockaddr_in` instead of `struct sockaddr` and cast the address of these structs to `struct sockaddr *` anytime you interact with a socket function.  This is the expected way to use these functions.

Comment: Okay I see.. But if I am doing this while in a while loop calling `recvfrom` am I not eating up pointless time continually casting? I was just doing this so I would not have to cast 100 times a second.

Comment: @pbuzz007 Casting doesn't occur a significant runtime cost, if any, particularly between pointer types.  This is a case of premature optimization.

Comment: On a normal implementation, casting a pointer does not have **any** runtime cost. In any case, `recvfrom` costs at least 2000x (and likely 10000x) as much as any single operator evaluation so trying to optimize the latter makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return (or pass or otherwise use) `sockaddr` structs by value; a `sockaddr` is not an actual type for representing/containing the data but a misguided legacy abstraction from the early days of C and Unix for a "base class" that actual socket address types are "derived from".

If you're writing C++, which your question suggests despite you originally tagging it C, you should represent the data with your own class that exposes a `struct sockaddr *` to pass to socket functions that need it, while using an appropriate type for storage internally. However, normally it's a mistake, regardless of whether you're using C or C++, to create such objects manually anyway. You should just be using `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: I tagged with C++ but it would not properly format the code, it turned all green..

Comment: @pbuzz007: Tagging is not to tell the site how to syntax-highlight your code (does it even do that??) but to show your question to people it's relevant to.

Comment: Yes, tagging does change how the `code` stuff is displayed.